# Загрузка nuxt js на vps

Tags: vue.js

подскажите как мне загрузить nuxt приложение на centOS 7, 
У меня  есть  репозиторий, ввожу команду git clone "ссылка на репозиторий", 
Подскажите команды дальше, npm i > npm run build > npm start?
Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

К вашим командам могу только добавить это:

В производстве вам нужен диспетчер процессов, чтобы поддерживать сервер Node навсегда.

Хорошие пакеты для этого:[pm2](https://github.com/Unitech/PM2/), [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon), [forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever).

## Пример для [pm2](https://github.com/Unitech/PM2/):

#### install pm2 process manager

```
npm install -g pm2
```

#### startup script

```
pm2 startup
```

#### start process

```
pm2 start npm --name "my-app" -- run start
```

#### save process list

```
pm2 save
```

#### list all processes

```
pm2 l
```

---

После каждого развертывания вам необходимо перезапустить процесс:

```
pm2 restart my-app
```

Comment: Спасибо за совет! К сожалению похоже проблема не в этом, может ли быть проблемой версия ноды? Она 6.14.3..

Comment: а вы в вопросе не написали в чем у вас проблема, очень желательно конечно не ставить node меньше чем у вас при разработке

Comment: При вводе npm run build выводит - sh: nuxt: command not found, в разработке версия 8.11.3, на vps 6.14.3.

Comment: У них в package,json написано     `"node": ">=8.0.0", "npm": ">=5.0.0"`

Comment: Блин, понял! Спасибо Вам большое, вы не могли бы ссылку где написано про package.json?

Comment: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/blob/dev/package.json#L62